# Strategies to deal with overflowing in logical clocks?

Tags: clock, integer-overflow

I'm building a [database](https://github.com/yottaStore/yottaStore), and I'm working on the storage format. For each record I have a logical clock which increases by 1 every time there's a write operation, and I would like to be able to compare the clocks of two writes to understand which happened first.

How can I deal with overflowing/wrapping of the counter?

Solutions I thought:

- Use a very large counter (u64?) and ignore the possibility of overflow
- Use a second "epoch counter" in order to keep track of overflows
- Periodically reset all the counters when I deem it safe
- Use BigInt and variable length encoding

All the strategies I envisioned have ugly drawbacks. I saw in some papers that overflowing counters are considered a solved problem, without mentioning how they would solve it, which makes me think I'm missing something. Any advice on how to deal with this problem?

Comment: `u64` is good enough for ~20'000 years if you update every nanosecond. How many updates exactly do you need to track, and how many millennia after your death does it need to work for?

Comment: Definetly u64 is enough for my use case, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution

Comment: You haven't said what your use case _is_. Are a billion updates a second a practical possibility? More? Fewer? Is storing 64 bits a practical problem?

Comment: I mentioned it's part of the storage format for a database, where I would like to compare the time for different writes. Max update rate according to benchmark is between 2^20 and 2^30 per second, but it can reach 2^40 in case I turn the logical clock in a distributed vector clock.

Comment: OK, so worst case a 64-bit counter gives you 2^24 seconds, which is just over 6 months. That's the sort of information that needs to be in the question to make it actually answerable.

Comment: thanks. If it can be of help, the logical clock exist in a single thread, with no parallel access possible.

Comment: I might also add that the data is stored in NVMe blocks, so a reset protocol like used in the linked paper is not suitable, as it would require to rewrite millions or billions of storage blocks.
paper: http://www.cse.msu.edu/~sandeep/publications/rvc-podc2000/main.pdf